# Set length of D3 tree link based on variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, graph-visualization

I'm using a D3 tree and my nodes can be either type 1 or 2. I'd like it that if a node is marked as type 1, the link to it is a lot shorter. How would I do that? I'm working with this example tree: https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.
You might want to fork the linked observable notebook, and adapt it so that your data structure is read.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a play with the Observable link and it looks like there are 3 snippets of code you need to change to make the links shorter:

```
// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y0/2},${source.x0})`)


 // Transition nodes to their new position.
 const nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition(transition)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y/2},${d.x})`)

diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal().x(d => d.y/2).y(d => d.x)
```

I've added "/2" to half the width of the links.

So to make this conditional, you could try adding an if statement in the above 3 places?

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately I'm having trouble doing a conditional with the diagonal - it gives the error `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function link() ...` Here's the code: `link
    .merge(linkEnter)
    .transition(transition)
    .attr('d', d => d.target.data.value == 1 ? diagonal_sm : diagonal)` Diagonal_sm is just the same diagonal function but with the dividing by two. My json has a field called "value" that I'm doing the conditional with.

Comment: Hi there.  You are adding the condition to the wrong attribute.

Comment: .attr("transform", d => d => d.target.data.value === 1 ? "translate(" + (d.y/2) + "," + d.x + ")" : "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")")

Comment: It's in a comment so I may have got the syntax a bit wrong but hopefully useful...

Comment: You then need to do a separate condition for diagonal:

Comment: diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal().x(d => d.target.dat.value === 1 ? d.y/2 : d.y).y(d => d.x)

Comment: CodePen might be easier?!?